# Python SDK equivalent of the rest api endpoint apigateway.locations.get?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-api-gateway

I am trying to find the python sdk equivalent of the rest api endpoint `apigateway.locations.get`.  Here is the [URL](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations/list) for the rest api documentation.

I couldn't find any documentation on how to achieve the same using their python SDK. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you mean you are looking for a dedicated library that perform that call?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes please. I couldn't find one in https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, the library [google-cloud-api-gateway](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/apigateway/latest) doesn't include that API Call.

That's why, the [discovery API](https://developers.google.com/discovery) exists to fill the gap between the library and the APIs.

```
import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

service = build('apigateway', 'v1')
resp = service.projects().locations().list(name="projects/<PROJECT_ID>").execute()
print(resp)
```